# Issue during Grouping and Ungrouping using Apache POI and java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, excel-2007

I am able to write to excel Sheet by Using Apache POI with Java.
Also, I am able to groupby Row, as mentioned in the requirement.
But, the issue which I am facing is:
I create multiple sheets in the workbook, and use "groupRow" to group data in the sheets.
And, I need to activate the 2nd sheet, by default. All, works fine, apart from the expand(+) button to "Ungroup" the "group".
Basically, when I open the excel, the 2nd sheet is selected by default and the similiar data are grouped also. But, when I click the "Ungroup" button(+), It does not work.
Note: If I navigate to some other sheet and come back to the same sheet, then the "Ungroup" button works fine.
Its due to the fact that the "Data Tab" is deactivated by default.
How do I activate the "Data Tab" by default, so that the "Ungroup" button works fine.
So, Basically, I need the "Ungroup" button to work ,without navigating to some other sheet.
Appreciate your help and Support.
If possible please share code snippet.

Below are the code Snippets:

```
sheetx = wb.createSheet();
sheetx.groupRow(4, 11);
sheetx.setRowGroupCollapsed(4, true);
wb.setActiveSheet(1);
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you post a sample document?

Comment: Usually it is easiest if you upload it to dropbox, google-drive or some other binary sharing platform.

Comment: Hi @centic, I have uploaded in dropbox. Please find the link below :https://www.dropbox.com/s/tl6jkwfnhulhaho/Sample.xlsx?dl=0   . The password of the excel is abc . you might get error while opening the sheet, click "yes" and continue.

Comment: Hm, the "error while opening the sheet" might even be related, you probably need to narrow down, why it happens, i.e. is it only happening with grouping and can you narrow it down into a small self-sufficient sample to report a bug for POI?

Comment: Hi @centic, the "error while opening the sheet" is not related. As in my actual scenario, I am not getting any error. This error might have popped  up, as I had to modify my code to get rid of actual data and information. Else, the behavior after the excel sheet opens is same.

Comment: Can anyone help on this issue?